# How to force a Float to only have four decimal places

Tags: java-me, floating-point

How can I make that a float number only have 4 decimal places at most.
In my J2ME app I have two fields : unitPrice (4 decimal places) and quantity(3 decimal places) and when I multiply them I got number with more decimals than I need:

```
unitPrice :5.6538
quantity: 5

result: 28.269001
```

What can I do to have a result of only 4 decimals? and in general what do I need to do to use floats with a specific number of decimals.

Comment: floats and doubles do not work that way. Please read [here](http://floating-point-gui.de/).

Answer (score 1):

Of course, if you were using Java SE the solution would be BigDecimal.

You could round as shown in the `result` initialization in the following program:

```
import java.math.BigDecimal;

public class Test {
  public static void main(String args[]) {
    float unitPrice = 5.6538f;
    float quantity = 5;
    float rawResult = quantity*unitPrice;
    System.out.println(rawResult);
    float result = Math.round(10000f*rawResult)/10000f;
    System.out.println(result);
    System.out.println(new BigDecimal(result));
  }
}
```

The output is:

```
28.269001
28.269
28.2689990997314453125
```

Unfortunately, as shown by the final printout using BigDecimal, `result` is not really exactly 28.269. 28.269 is not exactly representable in any binary fraction format. That could affect future calculations if decimal fractions are really important.

As an alternative, consider doing everything in integers, with each type of data having an associated power-of-ten factor. For unit price, the factor would be 10,000. For quantity, it would be 1000.

For the product, you want it to be 10,000. The intermediate result of doing the multiplication will have a factor of 10^7, so divide by 1000 and round to an integer.

Answer (score 0):

in vb6.0 we can use RonudOff() function for this operation; 
example:
unitPrice :5.6538
quantity: 5

result: 28.269001
then " RounOff(result)" will give 28.2690;

i think their may be some similar function in java also

thanks